# How to convert first column in df as a header and keep original header as sub-header

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I do have this type of data:

```
id <- c('id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2')
var1 <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var2 <-  round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var3  <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var4 <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
tbl <- tibble(id, var1, var2, var3, var4)

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  id     var1  var2   var3  var4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 id_1  1.62  6.36  9.69    2.44
2 id_1  6.10  8.49  8.37    7.75
3 id_1  1.28  7.58  7.03    9.43
4 id_1  5.71  4.94  0.0167 10.0 
5 id_2  7.75  0.836 9.31    2.36
6 id_2  1.38  2.35  2.94    6.01
7 id_2  0.560 6.63  3.51    4.04
8 id_2  1.9   9.29  0.230   1.83
```

And I would like to create a new tibble using the 'id' as a header and var1:var2 as a sub-header, something like this:

```
        id1                          id2 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     var1  var2   var3  var4          var1  var2   var3  var4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1.62  6.36  9.69    2.44        7.75  0.836 9.31    2.36
     6.10  8.49  8.37    7.75        1.38  2.35  2.94    6.01
     1.28  7.58  7.03    9.43        0.560 6.63  3.51    4.04
     5.71  4.94  0.0167  10.0        1.9   9.29  0.230   1.83
```

So far, I've been playing with pivot longer but I couldn't manage to get my desired output. I've also played with `group_by(sample_id)` and then transpose, but still not success. Does anyone could suggest a hint? I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
id <- c('id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2')
var1 <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var2 <-  round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var3  <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
var4 <- round(runif(n = 8, min = 0, max = 10), 4)
tbl <- tibble(id, var1, var2, var3, var4)

tbl |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  mutate(id = paste(id, name, sep = "_"))|> 
  select(-name) |>
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = value) |> 
  select(-rowid)


#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>   rowid id_1_var1 id_1_var2 id_1_var3 id_1_var4 id_2_var1 id_2_var2 id_2_var3
#>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1      2.88      5.51     2.46       6.56     9.40       6.78      8.90
#> 2     2      7.88      4.57     0.421      7.09     0.456      5.73      6.93
#> 3     3      4.09      9.57     3.28       5.44     5.28       1.03      6.41
#> 4     4      8.83      4.53     9.54       5.94     8.92       9.00      9.94
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: id_2_var4 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To present the data including grouped headings use a table presentation package, for example `kableExtra` (there are several others which can do this too)

library(kableExtra)
kbl(tbl1,
col.names = rep(paste0("var_", 1:4), 2),
digits = 2) |>
add_header_above(c("id_1" = 4, "id_2" = 4)) |>
column_spec(1:8, width = "15mm")

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I managed to pivot the data as you suggest. However,  what we are missing is the main header (id2, id2) and the subheader (var1:var4) as Illustrated in my question

Comment: You cannot do that with tibble, I'll show you how to do this with kableExtra as an example of presenting the data.

Comment: that would be great! And makes sense why I did struggle a lot ....

Comment: See updated answer which includes a version of the table presentation that you are looking for.